# How to re-use type identifier in nested C++ class?

Tags: c++, types, nested, identifier

In C++, is there a standard-compliant way of re-using a type identifier from a surrounding context within a nested class? In the example below, consider the identifier `Type`.

```
template<class T>
struct A {
    typedef T Type;

    struct B {
        typedef typename A::Type Type;
    };
};
```

Comment: And what's wrong with the code you show us? The name `A::Type` is different from the name `A::B::Type`. Could you please elaborate on what problem you're having, and what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks, Joachim. I got confused. Will delete the question.

Comment: Un-deleting this question. I agree that the example above is correct and standard compliant. However, in a different case which I have not yet reduced to a minimal non-working example, I get an error message 'declaration of ... changes meaning of ... from ...'. Any suggestions?

Comment: Identified and solved my problem. I was using `Type` (more precisely, `A::Type`) in a different typedef in `B` before defining `B::Type` and hence re-defining the meaning of `Type` in `B`. Apparently, this is not standard-compliant. Thanks again, Joachim.